# How to use live()?

Tags: jquery

I have a script where in i want to use live in below code.

```
if($('#Menu').length >0) {
   $('#Menu >li').click(function() {

   });  
}
```

How can i use it ?

Comment: If you use jQuery >= 1.7 you shouldn't start to learn about .live() because it will soon be deprecated (maybe it already is). You should rather start learning about .on() `$(document).on('click', '#Menu >li', function() {...});`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `live` as it's deprecated as of 1.7

```
if($('#Menu').length) {
   $('#Menu').on('click', '> li', function() {

   });  
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/live/

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live().

In case you are using jQuery version `< 1.7` and `>= 1.4.2`, you can use [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

```
   $('#Menu').delegate('> li', 'click', function() { // different argument order than on

   });
```

Comment: To be picky... `if ($('#Menu').length) { ... }`

Comment: @elclanrs I shall follow your pickiness, master

Comment: Don't you think `$('#Menu').length` is pointless here? See my answer for the reason.

Comment: i tried $('.menuDiv').on('click', 'li', function() {
alert(".-.");
   }); it says on() not a function. Can't i bind it to class ?

Comment: @user1184100: Then it means your jQuery is older than 1.7. You should try to use `.delegate()` then. Plus this answer skipped `>` character from the selector (which is a meaningful part).

Comment: @Tadeck thanks for pointing that out, will edit for correctness

Answer (score 2):

You don't.

`.live()` was deprecated in favor of `.delegate()`, then `.delegate()` (and `.bind()` etc.) was deprecated in favor of `.on()`.

### Example implementation of of `.live()`'s successor

This could give you similar result:

```
$('#Menu').on('click', '> li', function(){

});
```

### If you do not have `.on()`, use `.delegate()`

As I mentioned, `.live()` was deprecated in favor of [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), so if you do not have `.on()` available in your version of jQuery, you should try to use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) first:

```
$('#Menu').delegate('> li', 'click', function(){

});
```

### `live()` example doing something similar

If you insist on `.live()`, you can write code like that:

```
$('#Menu > li').live('click', function(){

});
```

### Corrected example from the question

In general you do not need to check if something exists to add a event handler to it. jQuery will search for the element and if not found, it will just not add event handler, so you can write:

```
$('#Menu >li').click(function() {

});
```

instead of what you have written in your question.

Answer (score 1):

[.live( events, handler(eventObject) )](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
<script>
$("#Menu >li").live("click", function(){

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should not use `live`.
you should use `on`

the Live is deprecated - and should not be used.
p.s. this also replace the delegate syntax - if you wish...

you dont have to supply the second param - then it will listen to the container itself and all its childs +subchilds.
since (1.7+)

example :

```
$(".myDiv").on("click","#myButton",function (){
alert('1');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think something like below:

```
if($('#Menu').length >0) {
   $('#Menu >li').live('click', function() {

   });  
}
```

[live](http://api.jquery.com/live)

Answer (score 1):

As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

In your case you can use like this

```
if($('#Menu').length >0) {
   $('#Menu >li').live("click", function() {

   });  
}
```